# How do I copy entire contents of file (>1 pane) in Tmux emacs copy mode?

Tags: emacs, tmux

i want to copy the entire contents of a file using emacs copy mode in tmux.

however when i enter copy mode, type C-space to start highlighting text, and then type M-> to jump to the end of the file, i end up just jumping to the file info section at the bottom of the tmux pane.

here's a pic showing what happens:

edit: i'm a new user and apparently can't post a pic yet. but basically you could imagine the yellow highlighted (selected) text in tmux copy mode. instead of the end of the file i can only highlight to the bottom of the pane (which looks kinda like this):

```
-u-:----F1 file_name.rb      Top L1      (Ruby)---------------------------------
```

my question is, how can i enter copy mode, start selecting text, and jump to the end of the file?

and if this isn't the best way to accomplish my goal (of copying an entire file's contents while in tmux), what's a better way of doing it?

thx!

p.s.

i've followed the instructions here: https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard

and also the instructions from the pragmatic tmux book.

in case it helps, here're the relevant lines from my .tmux.conf file (which i mostly copied from the pragmatic tmux book):

```
# use pbcopy|pbpaste wrapper script
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"

# send contents of current tmux buffer to system clipboard
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"

# support pasting from the system clipboard
bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer $(reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste); tmux paste buffer"

# overriding "auto-detection" to always use emacs
set-option -g status-keys emacs
set-option -gw mode-keys emacs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tmux* does not really understand that you are running *emacs* in the tty that it has provided. It only knows what has been written to that tty; so, when you press M-> while in *tmux* `copy-mode`, it simply moves to the bottom of the pane’s scrollback history (M-> while in `copy-mode` runs the (`copy-mode`-specific) *tmux* command `history-bottom`).

You really need to approach this problem from inside *emacs*. Here are some (interactively runnable) example functions that you could bind to key in *emacs*:

```
(defun write-region-to-tmux-buffer (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region beg end "tmux load-buffer -" nil nil nil t))

(defun write-buffer-to-tmux-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (write-region-to-tmux-buffer (point-min) (point-max)))
```

If you want to bypass the buffer and use the file instead (i.e. create a buffer from the file on the disk, not the (possibly modified) contents of the buffer), you might use something like this:

```
(defun write-buffer-file-to-tmux-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fn (buffer-file-name)))
    (if fn
        (shell-command
         (concat "tmux load-buffer "
                 (shell-quote-argument fn)))
      (error "Not a file-backed buffer"))))
```

Comment: thx for the answer. since i've only copied/pasted emacs configs thus far, it might take some hacking for me to figure this out. so i'll revisit your answer once i've figured it out.  
**note:** i have o'reilly's "learning GNU emacs, 3d ed.," "writing GNU emacs extensions," as well as the FSF's "GNU emacs manual" for reference. if you're familiar w/ these sources (or other reference material) -- and have a few minutes to spare -- feel free to point me toward the information that will teach me to use your example functions to bind to key in emacs. -thx!

Comment: I am really not much of an Emacs user, but something like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'write-region-to-tmux-buffer)` will probably work (i.e. in your `.emacs` file, along with the function definition(s)).

Comment: that's awesome - thx! to solve i added `(defun write-buffer-file-to-tmux-buffer ()...` and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") 'write-buffer-file-to-tmux-buffer)` to my ~/.emacs file. then, inside of tmux, i emacs'd into a file, pressed `C-c t` then `[prefix] C-c` and pasted the output into TextEdit.app (to test). worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes and it’s pretty easy:

You need to run one of the tmux commands. You can run a tmux command by doing Ctrl+b+: and typing the command.

```
load-buffer path
```

or

```
loadb path
```

for short

Comment: yep this also works. seems to be more convenient for copying contents of files when not actually viewing the files in tmux.